# How to calculate file contents difference?

Tags: unix, sed, grep

I have two files `large_input` and `subset_input` file and their contents could be

`large_input`

```
1
34
65
7643
hello
we
```

`subset_input`

```
65
we
hello
34
```

In this case `sort` command is not very helpful, otherwise `sort | uniq` on both files following by `diff` would had been very useful

**Question**
In such scenarion where data can not be sorted(because of its contents), whats the best way to find out

`large_input` - `subset_input` which would be

```
1
7643
```

Comment: Why doesn't `sort | uniq` work? I did precisely what you said and got this: `0a1
> 1
2a4
> 7643` as the diff. Maybe you want to try `sort -g`

Comment: Why isn't `sort` helpful? It will sort it in lexicographic order, but that shouldn't matter; the exact order shouldn't matter if you just want to do set difference, as long as it's consistent.

Comment: `sort -g` did the trick, thank you @skjaidev.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
diff <(sort file1) <(sort file2) | sed '/^[0-9][0-9]*[acd][0-9]*/d;s/^[<>] //'
```

works for me,

output:

```
1
7643
```

Some shells don't support `<(sort fileX)`, so you might have to presort file files in-place like `sort -o file1 file1; sort file -o file2 file2; ....`

The sed expressions remove the output from `diff`. To see what it is doing, first remove the sed completely, the add back 1 section (delimited by semicolon) at a time.

I hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

This is exactly what [`comm`](http://man.cx/comm) is made for:

```
comm -23 <(sort large_input) <(sort subset_input)
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use sed to produce a sed script that does the job:

```
sed -e 's#^#/^#' -e 's#$#$/d#' subset_input > sed_script
```

Then applying this sed script to your large_input is easy:

```
sed -f sed_script large_input
```

If you have bash, it can be done without a temporary file:

```
sed -f <(sed -e 's#^#/^#' -e 's#$#$/d#' subset_input) large_input
```

This solution only applies to a subset_input of 'reasonable' size though.